# xampp Pid(s) not stable

Tags: php, xampp, pid

[image]
Hi,

I am facing error in recent times in xampp. i have developed a internal tool where 50 members used to login and clock their daily reports. it is still in developing stage so we are running a PC as a server and working locally. if you check the above link image you will see screen shot on left is working fine but suddenly one Pid(s) is disappearing  and changes yellow during that time the program is not working and its need a refresh (image on right). can any one please let me know what should i look after to fix this issue..

This problem occurs when more users login and start clocking their report. when it crosses 30 members this problem starts or else it is working fine. But the numbers gets reducing as the day increases. once this problem started after a week only 20 members can login the next week 10 members can only login if more members login the error starts. finally i have to re-install the xampp.

[Error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unUDt.jpg)

please check my Error image 2. this error totally stops the apache to run and if i click cancel the process starts working. this is happening irrespective of time some times its coming frequently some times its coming after 3 or 5 hours.
During this error the page cant be reached.

If the apache turns yellow and single Pid(s) is displaying during that changing time the page cannot be reached. this happens in just 2 seconds but frequently every 1 min or 2 min.

Comment: I think Running as administrator is not a problem because when less members are logged it the system is working fine for example if 20 members logged it its working good when it goes higher more than 30 members the problem starts. apache cannot handle it.

Comment: @pradeep You cannot be certain at this stage it's a duplicate

Comment: @Baala - Please add some reference to the warning message in the body of your question. For example, what happens when you try running it with admin privileges?

Comment: @Boaz i have edited please check the Error image 2

Comment: It’s difficult to debug the issue from this information. I suggest to check the usual suspects like available disk space and memory. Our sister site Server Fault is probably more suitable for this issue.

Comment: Yes i have checked all the aspect like space and memory. its all enough. what is your sister site server fault can you share it @Boaz.

Comment: https://serverfault.com